# LocationManager heading calibration showing way too much

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have a compass in my app, so I made sure to set the `locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:` method to `YES`. However, my users have reported (I see it too) that the calibration screen seems to come up WAY too often, even when it seems there is no way that iOS detected a magnetic change.

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager {
    return YES;
}
```

**Are there any options here to make it not so sensitive? Or am I safe to turn it off completely?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set sensitive like this

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager
{
CLLocationDirection accuracy = [[manager heading] headingAccuracy];
if(accuracy < 0.0f || accuracy > 10.0f)
{
  return YES;
}
else 
{
  return NO;
}
}
```